# After setting up Sync Center can no longer browse the unsynced network files

Tags: windows-10, offline-files, sync-center

My corporate VPN occasionally drops out so I set up Offline Files in Sync Centre to make a key directory available when offline.

However, now that is the only directory I can see on the server in Windows Explorer.

How can I get access to the original server contents while maintaining one directory available offline?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge.

First, you should need to be able to connect the server that the sharing folders you want to access. try to ping the ip of the server, if it is unreachable, add the ip route to point to the server and back to client.

Then you should be able to access the sharing folders by IP, if you want to use hostname, you need to add the DNS record on the Local DNS server, if no DNS, you can add the host file.
**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file**

Make sure that the VPN user has the permissions to access the sharing folders.